# Both are using Expand Around Center Algorithm for finding longest palindromic substring and why is one faster a lot?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is the faster solution A that only perform 6ms on leetcode and it's almost as fast as Manacher Algorithm(6ms on leetcode).

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        if (s.empty()) return "";
        if (s.size() == 1) return s;
        int min_start = 0, max_len = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size();) {
            if (s.size() - i <= max_len / 2) break;
            int j = i, k = i;
            while (k < s.size()-1 && s[k+1] == s[k]) ++k; // Skip duplicate characters.
            i = k+1;
            while (k < s.size()-1 && j > 0 && s[k + 1] == s[j - 1]) { ++k; --j; } // Expand.
            int new_len = k - j + 1;
            if (new_len > max_len) { min_start = j; max_len = new_len; }
        }
        return s.substr(min_start, max_len);
    }
};
```

And I don't understand why the blow solution B is slow to much compared with solution A, which costs 16ms runtime.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int expandAroundCenter(string s, int left,int right) {
        int L = left, R = right;
        while(L >=0 && R < s.length() && s[L] == s[R]) {
            L--;
            R++;
        }

        return R - L - 1;
    }

    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        int start = 0, end = 0;
        if (s.empty()) return "";
        if (s.size() == 1) return s;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int len1 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i);
            int len2 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i + 1);
            int len = std::max(len1, len2);
            if(len > end - start + 1) {
                start = i - (len - 1) / 2;
                end = i + len / 2;
            }

            if(start + len > s.length()) break;
        }

        return s.substr(start, end - start + 1);
    }

};
```

Since they are both Expand Around Center Algorithm and get O(N^2) time complexity and O(1) space complexity(Manacher's Algorithm gets O(n) time complexity), I can only speculate the coding method is the most important factor. Well, if it's the case and I really want to know why.

With the optimazation, solution B is still slower 50% than A.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int expandAroundCenter(const string& s, int left,int right) {
        int L = left, R = right;
        while(L >=0 && R < s.length() && s[L] == s[R]) {
            L--;
            R++;
        }

        return R - L - 1;
    }

    string longestPalindrome(const string& s) {
        int max_len = 0;
        int min_start = 0;
        if (s.empty()) return "";
        if (s.size() == 1) return s;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.size() - i <= max_len / 2) 
                break;

            int j = i, k = i;
            while (k < s.size()-1 && s[k+1] == s[k]) ++k;
            int len = expandAroundCenter(s, j, k);

            if(len > max_len) {
                max_len = len;
                min_start = j - (len - (k - j + 1)) / 2;
            }
        }

        return s.substr(min_start, max_len);
    }

};
```

Comment: Count how many times you're copying the string in each case.

Comment: Yes, I'm not aware of the frequent string copy costs. Solution B runs faster by passing a const reference. @molbdnilo Thank you. Besides,  the code snippet of skipping repeated characters is another optimization. 
However, solution B is still 50% slower than A.

Comment: Now it's just overhead from the function call itself. Can't skip that, unless the compiler decides to inline.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm A skips pumped character sequences first which most likely make up for a significant portion of the benchmark. Algorithm B falls for that trap and iterates over the pumped sequence twice, once for each call of the predicate.

Take the benchmark suite, and replace all single character repetitions by a `[Pad][Character][Pad]`, then this optimization breaks.

Comment: Yes. After code optimization, Solution B's runtime benchmark performance was reduced from 16ms to 9ms.